# What map was used for the Mann vs. Machine trailer?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-mann-vs-machine

What was the map was used for the [Mann vs. Machine trailer](http://youtu.be/C4cfo0f88Ug)? I'm guessing it was just for the trailer, but I'm sure it exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A modified version of Viaduct, [claims the TF2 wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Mann_vs._Machine_(teaser)). They're walking towards the point from below the sniper ledge at 0:40.

Comment: Well when the trailer first starts where are they walking from? the video first begins with Heavy walking around a corner then getting the others to come with them. Towards the end they look to be walking towards the blue/blu spawn/area? Also do you think there may be a map stored somewhere?

Comment: @Scootaloo Those areas are likely the ones most heavily modified for the purposes of the video. I'm afraid Valve didn't distribute them.